# Lua: implicit table creation with string keys - why the extra brackets?

Tags: lua

Say that you want to create a Lua table, and all its keys are valid lua identifiers. Then you can use the `key=value` syntax:

```
local niceTable = { I=1, like=1, this=1, syntax=1 }
```

If however your strings are not "identifiable", then you have to use the `['key']=value` syntax:

```
local operators = { ['*']="Why", ['+']="the", ['/']="brackets", ['?']='?' }
```

I'm a bit baffled about this. What are those brackets doing there? What do they mean?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They identify the contained string as a key in the resulting table. The first form, you could consider as equal to

```
local niceTable = {}
niceTable.I = 1;
niceTable.like = 1;
```

The second form is equal to

```
local operators = {}
operators['*'] = "Why";
operators['+'] = "The";
```

The difference is purely syntactic sugar, except where the first one uses identifiers, so it has to follow the identifier rules, such as doesn't start with a number and interpret-time constant, and the second form uses any old string, so it can be determined at runtime, for example, and a string that's not a legal identifier. However, the result is fundamentally the same. The need for the brackets is easily explained.

```
local var = 5;
local table = {
    var = 5;
};
-- table.var = 5;
```

Here, var is the identifier, not the variable.

```
local table = {
    [var] = 5;
};
-- table[5] = 5;
```

Here, var is the variable, not the identifier.

Comment: So it is basically a syntactic way to differentiate between "the value of var" and the "var value" :) Thanks for your answer, I think I understand now. I think I prefer Ruby's way of doing things (It always requires the complete key, no shortcuts, but has a shortcut syntax for identifiable strings)

Comment: best syntax sugar in the world

Answer (score 28):

The normal syntax for indexing a table is `t[val]`. For string keys only, Lua provides an *alternate* syntax, where `t.foo` is exactly equivalent to `t["foo"]`. This is purely a syntactical convenience, so-called 'syntax sugar'. It doesn't add functionality, it just gives you a less cluttered syntax for using strings as named fields.

There are a lot of strings keys this won't work for:

```
t["hello_world"] => t.hello_world  -- works
t["hello world"] => t.hello world  -- oops, space in the string
t["5 * 3"]       => t.5 * 3        -- oops
t['[10]']        => t.[10]         -- oops
```

Basically it only works if the string key would be a valid identifier.

Again, tables are indexed via `[]`, and in most cases you need to use them:

```
t = {
   -- [key]           = value
   [10]               = "ten", -- number key, string value
   ["print function"] = print, -- string key, function value
   ["sub table"]      = {},    -- string key, table value
   [print]            = 111,   -- function key, number value
   ["foo"]            = 123,   -- string key, number value
}
```

Only if you're using a string key which would work as a valid identifier (no spaces, contains only word characters, numbers, or underlines, and doesn't begin with a number) can you use the shortcut syntax. For the table above, that would be only 'foo':

```
t = {
   -- [key]           = value
   [10]               = "ten", -- number key, string value
   ["print function"] = print, -- string key, function value
   ["sub table"]      = {},    -- string key, table value
   [print]            = 111,   -- function key, number value
   foo                = 123,   -- string key, number value
}
```

Comment: [=[ [print]            = 111,   -- table  key, number value ]=]
should be function key :)

Comment: @jpjacoms,daurnimator: Right you are! I included specifically for that reason. copy-and-paste-and-forget-to-edit error. Fixed.

Comment: Both answers are good, but DeadMG's came a little earlier - I'm going to give this one to him. But +1 for you Mud!