# Fighting a bit with lua table indexing

Tags: lua, subset, lua-table

I am new to Lua, and would like to understand the following syntax:

```
init_state_global = some_integer
rnn_state = {[0] = init_state_global}
```

My Pythonic interpretation would be that the first element has index 0 and that the value of the element is equal to the variable init_state_global.

However, when I do

```
print(rnn_state[0])
```

I get

```
>> nil
```

Can someone can help me interpret this:

```
rnn_state = {[0] = init_state_global}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua: implicit table creation with string keys - why the extra brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514636/lua-implicit-table-creation-with-string-keys-why-the-extra-brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua, you do it before the expression set(=) and after the array name. Also, Lua uses 1-based index

```
init_state_global = some_integer
rnn_state = {}
rnn_state[1] = init_state_global;
```

Perhaps you forgot to declare a variable:

```
init_state_global = 5
rnn_state = {[0] = init_state_global}
print(rnn_state[0])
```

Comment: right, but what does rnn_state = {[0] = init_state_global} mean? I picked the line from actual code but I am struggling with it.

Answer (score 2):

it turns out it is easier than I thought.

Even though lua starts indexing at 1, you can set an index ad hoc to zero.

So 
    rnn_state = {[0] = init_state_global}

means just that,

```
rnn_state[0] = init_state_global
```

However, I stated above that

```
print(rnn_state[0]) was equal to
>> nil
```

that is because I forgot to declare the variable (in my code, not in the initial thread)

```
init_state_global = some_integer
```

:(

So if you declare the variable correctly, the following statement

```
print(rnn_state[0])
```

will return

```
>> some_integer
```

if you previously declared

```
init_state_global = some_integer
```

Another thing (may not be obvious to those of us used to python lists) is that

```
rnn_state = {}
rnn_state[0] = 4
```

is the same as

```
rnn_state = {[0] = 4}
```

Comment: But you shouldn't ignore the fact that table's numerical index starts at 1 and so the internal array part. With 0 or negative numbers or strings or whatever you create an entry in the internal hashtable which has slower access.